# Heat of 12 LED lights 60mA 3.6W PCB

Tags: voltage, power, led, pcb, current

I’ve designed a PCB that is 50mm by 48mm

It’s a simple 12 LED light board, each LED has its own 36 ohm resistor and is all powered by a 5V supply

each LED runs off 60mA and uses 0.306W

The resistors are 1/4 resistors

[image]

Ohms law states that 12 LEDs at 60mA is 3.6W (720mA)

The LEDs are in parallel.

Will this get hot, to hot to run on its own? And is their a chance of it over heating and becoming dangerous?

Comment: How is your board physically connected to the rest of the world? What is the thermal conductivity of its physical mounting, and what is the amount of airflow around it? What is the maximum ambient temperature?

Comment: One important question also is: what LEDs are you using?

Comment: https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Light-Emitting-Diodes-LED_HONGLITRONIC-Hongli-Zhihui-HONGLITRONIC-HL-AM-2835H489W-S1-08HL-HR3_C210314.html?fbclid=IwAR2Xqt2J8FKnp-eglkdV9N2PK8ilMbhgDPINY1FFuqpnGbBzcZFHwnkLlg4

Comment: Are you sure you are running these at 60 mA? With a target of 3.2V at 60 mA you want a 30 ohm resistor. With a 36, the current drops down closer to 50 mA. Better for your led life, less heat too. The actual current and voltage balance may be off from what you expect

Answer (score 0):

The LED will not turn all the power to heat. Most lighting LEDs have an efficiency of more than 70%. This means, for the worst lighting LEDs, you will turn about 30% of input power to heat. Also, every resistor will dissipate about 0.129W too. This means 12*0.129=1.55W power dissipation on all resistors. Removing this from the input power (3.6W), only about 2W is delivered to LEDs. This means, for a bad LED, you will dissipate about 30%*2W=0.6W power on all 12 LEDs. That and 1.55W dissipation on resistors can warm up a PCB; but for a 0.25W resistor and most LEDs, you will have no problem.

Comment: 70% efficiency for `worst leds`?! From my experience, only the best leds reach efficiency of over 60%. I would assume an efficiency of 30% as approximation

Comment: These LEDs are designed for lighting. They have more efficiency than normal LEDs. It depends on the current, temperature and etc. But they can reach up to 85% in some conditions. What I explained in the answer is a general description. Maybe this help: https://www.digikey.fr/fr/articles/identifying-the-causes-of-led-efficiency-droop
 Also, I edited the answer, to be clear I mean this efficiency is for lighting LEDs.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. The LM301 by Samsung, one of the most famous leds for lighting, has an efficiency of ~60%. Can you give a reference for an led with such high efficiency? I'd really be interested...

Comment: No; That's the most efficient LED. I don't know any LED with more than 200lm/w efficiency. But where did you find that this LED has an efficiency of ~60%? I could not find that anywhere. There are some general efficiency diagrams like the like in my latest comment. Also, the manufacturers just provide the lm/w efficiency, and by comparing to Incandescent and fluorescent lamp the efficiency of these LEDs must more than 60%.

Comment: I did calculations using the spectrum samsung provides in the LM301 datasheet. You misunderstand the meaning of lumens in this context: incandescant lamps are *not that inefficient* in turning electrical power to radiation. The important point is that most of the emitted radiation is invisble, which results in few lumens. Even if the electrical-to-radiation efficiency of both led and incandescent lamp were the same, leds would still be far more efficient in terms of lm/W simply because they emit in a narrow, visible region.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are running these at 60 mA? With a target of 3.2V at 60 mA you want a 30 ohm resistor. With a 36, the current drops down closer to 50 mA. Better for your led life, less heat too. The actual current and voltage balance may be off from what you expect.

As to whether things will get too hot? Even with everything combined it shouldn't. Assuming the specs you've given would be 3.6 Watts for the entire board. The 0.306 W you mentioned isn't for what you are running either. That number is the Pd for the absolute max rating at 90 mA which you shouldn't be running. But between the 3.2V @ 60 mA and the resistor at 1.8V @ 60 mA, then you are pretty close to 0.300 W. Each part will get a bit warm but at under 1/4 Watt they will still be touchable. But since the math is likely off its going to be less than 3.6 Watts. I bet it will be 3 Watts. ***Plus*** the leds will only convert part into heat. You may not feel them get too warm at all.

That said, you do have some things you can fix. ***Your traces? TINY.*** All that board space and you have these thin little traces. Make the positive traces thicker and use the extra board space for a ground pour. Is this a double sided board from a pcb maker? Use vias and place the ground on the entire backside. All the extra copper will help distribute the heat so you don't have little pin pricks of heat at the leds and resistors. Think of it as a free heat sink!